# Unity crashes at build launch

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, crash

Unity 2022.3.7f1 LTS. Builded at Win 10 x64. In the editor and play mode, everything works as it should. The build is built without errors and warnings. The build includes one test scene and several game objects in it, as well as in resources. After the build is launched, the “Made with Unity” window appears for a second, after which the client crashes. In a practical way, it was determined that the build crashes, provided that one of the scripts in the scene has a link to the prefab in the resources. If you leave the null field and collect, the scene starts and works. It is necessary to assign a serializable field some value other than null - and hello. I assumed that something was wrong with the packages, reset them to default settings and set the required minimum. It didn’t have any effect. The script with which I associate the possible cause of this obscenity is nothing special, it is a common monobeh for managing a pool of objects. The presence or absence of the pool itself in the script does not affect anything, I also sinned against this.
I found out that error 0x80000003 occurs in the module Build/UnityPlayer.dll from Windows events log. Reinstalled the new version of the editor, performed the recommended actions (include registry fix, RAM checking etc)that I found on the Internet for this error, zero sense. What else can be done in this case?

Was done RAM checking with MemTest86, regictry fixing with CCleaner, Windows Defender and firewall turns off. New editor installation. Virus checking.

UPD
log:
The Project.exe version 2022.3.8.60156 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To find out if there is any additional information about the problem, check the issue log in the Security and Maintenance section in the Control Panel.
Process ID: 13 b4
Start time: 01d9dbd41b2d726f
Completion Time: 5
Application Path: F:\UnityProject\Build\Project.exe
Report ID: 91946bf1-a775-42b6-87ff-40e0941db3dd
Full name of the failure package:
The code of the application associated with the failed package:
Hang Type: Unknown

This log was created after last build and launch attempt. Previous are the same.
I suspect that this is not a unity problem, but an operating system problem.

Comment: What does the log say about it?

Comment: Added log to description

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.